# JavaScript in XSLT not outputting correctly

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is the node I need to output:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.Echo=document["standard"+"Write"]==null?document["write"]:document["standard"+"Write"];
    var include=function(path) {
        path="http://www.WebsiteName.com/eBay_files_ybr/js/"+path;
        document.Echo('<' + 'script src="' + path + '"' +' type="text\/javascript"><' + '\/script>');};
    include("jquery.js");
    include("accrodion-menu.js");
</script>
```

The problem I'm running into is (You guessed it) the less than sign after 'Echo' and after 'javascript'

Now I've already tried using `&lt;` and even `&amp;lt;`

I've even tried doing `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>` but that did not work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's JavaScript, not xslt. What is the xslt interpreter for this? A web browser?

Comment: Also, you should wrap your script content with `<![CDATA[]]>`

Comment: Can you post the XSLT you are using? Also, what processor are you using?

Comment: Neither the `language` nor the `type` attribute is necessary these days. Also, you should make sure you spell `accordion` correctly.

Comment: So this HTML was given to me to use as part of an XSLT. Almost all of the rest of it works, it's just this part that doesn't format right on the web page. 

I just tried wrapping the content in CDATA and that did not work. Still getting 'Echo('&lt;' +' when I inspect the element.

Comment: @StanleySinger Did any of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a dumb question on my part, but why not just replace all of that mess with this:

```
<xsl:variable name="scriptPath"
              select="'http://www.WebsiteName.com/eBay_files_ybr/js/'" />
<script src="{$scriptPath}jquery.js"> </script>
<script src="{$scriptPath}accordion-menu.js"> </script>
```

Comment: Because it would not load lazily.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the contents of your script tag in `CDATA` as a commenter suggested. You might then consider using `disable-output-escaping`, which would let the `<` be a `<` as text, and cause it to be output without escaping. However, the `<` in the JS in the HTML could still cause problems (especially if the output is being treated as XHTML). You really want the JS output into the HTML to be CDATA'd itself, which you accomplish using the `cdata-section-elements="script"` attribute in your `<xsl:output>`. This will wrap the output in CDATA, so it will both not be escaped, **and** will not cause any problem to the HTML parser.

```
<xsl:output ... cdata-section-elements='script'/>

<xsl:template ...
    <script><![CDATA[
        document.Echo=document["standard"+"Write"] == null ? document["write"] : document["standard"+"Write"];
        var include = function(path) {
            path = "http://www.WebsiteName.com/eBay_files_ybr/js/" + path;
            document.Echo('<script src="' + path + '"></script>');
        };
        include("jquery.js");
        include("accordion-menu.js");
    ]]></script>
    ...
</xsl:template>
```